# Does ant 1.10.x supports log4j2

Tags: java, ant, log4j, log4j2

I am upgrading log4j from 1.x to log4j2.x
In apache-ant-1.10.0-bin.tar.gz, I found ant-apache-log4j.pom points to the log4j 1.x version as follows :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.13</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Does ant 1.10.x supports log4j2?

Will changing version to log4j2.x manually work?

Answer (score 1):

Ant uses the log4j 1.x API, it will probably work if you use log4j2 together with the log4j 1.x bridge.

Ant itself doesn't use log4j at all, the only thing using it is `org.apache.tools.ant.listener.Log4jListener`.